# How do I import one html file and use it as a preset in another html file?

Tags: html, import

I have a template file that includes the basic structure of each sub-page of the main website.
How can I import this into my other sub pages? I have looked on the internet but I can't find anything. I have also tried:

```
<link rel="import" href="Preset.html">
```

However, that is not working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think there is any direct method to achieve it. You need to do it with JavaScript

Comment: @SumanBarick, Ok I don't know any code for that, do you?

Comment: I have found: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_template.asp however I still do not understand how I could use it throughout multiple files.

Comment: I have written a sample code in answer. It should help.

Comment: The link you shared is about <template> tag, that is for cloning / reusing a particular piece of HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps,

1. In your javascript file do an ajax to get the template file content
2. Now once you get the content in your JS file, put it inside some div container inside your html file

In your JS file

```
fetch('path_to_html_file_here')
.then(res => res.text())
.then(txt => document.getElementById('root').innerHTML = txt)
```

In your HTML file,

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

This method will put all the HTML present inside your template file inside that div with id "root". You can do this separately for header, footer and all the reusable parts.

Try it out, this is the simplest way. You must run it in local server, otherwise fetch will not work. Otherwise you can also use any declarative JS approach as in Angular or React.

Hope it helps :)